# Workflow Status Tasks: One or more field types are not installed properly

Tags: 2013, workflow, tasks

In the workflow status tasks, I get the error:

> "One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields"

I have opened up the fields one by one and they all seem to be fine. Then I started to delete them one by one until there were only basic fields such as title and other fields I could not delete. I still get the error.

[image]

Does anyone have any experience with this/know how to debug a similar issue?

Comment: Having the exact same issue. Wondering if the cause of this has been identified?

Comment: I think we had the content type inherit from "Task" instead of "Workflow Task" or something similar. Either way, this reply is too little too late but it might help someone else :P

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue. Following [@David's](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/17299/david) last comment we used "Workflow Task (SharePoint 2013)" as our base type and then the task list view started working.