# sharepoint workflow error- content type ID

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

Using SharePoint designer 2013 workflow and getting below error:

**> One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields.**

Workflow **Start Task process** fails in 2013 but works in 2010 for the same list.,

The workflow error is same in all the lists of site..

Need help to resolve this.

Screenshot of workflow:

[image]

Comment: Check if all the fields used in the workflow are available in the lists

Comment: The same error in all the lists, even tested with 2 dummy col. in new list. Workflow Task process fails, rest all works

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/80544/workflow-status-tasks-one-or-more-field-types-are-not-installed-properly

Comment: Thank you all. The issue got resolved, not sure how. But 2013 workflow task process started working only when i tried the task process with 2010 workflow. Once 2010 w/f executed then i retried with 2013 w/f it started working without any errors, removed 2010 w/f now and 2013 w/f task process works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the content type inherited from "Workflow Task", not from "Task".

Answer (score 0):

Go to Workflow Tasks list, make sure it allow the management of Content Types.
[image]

Then go back to List settings, and make sure **Workflow Task(SharePoint 2013)** content type is added. If not ,add it.

[image]